# App deployed successfully , but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: node.js, heroku

Below is the error:

$ heroku logs --tail
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970704+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/app.js:15:10)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970705+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970705+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10) {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970706+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970706+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970706+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970707+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-00.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970707+00:00 app[web.1]: _hostAddress: HostAddress {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970707+00:00 app[web.1]: isIPv6: false,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970708+00:00 app[web.1]: host: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-00.o9elntq.mongodb.net',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970708+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 27017
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970709+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970709+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-00.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970709+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970709+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970710+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970710+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970710+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970711+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970711+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970711+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970712+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 1394742968,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970712+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970713+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection  to 52.201.50.252:27017 closed
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970713+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970713+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket. (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970714+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970714+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:709:12
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970714+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7) {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970715+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970715+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970715+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970715+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-01.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970716+00:00 app[web.1]: _hostAddress: HostAddress {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970716+00:00 app[web.1]: isIPv6: false,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970717+00:00 app[web.1]: host: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-01.o9elntq.mongodb.net',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970717+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 27017
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970717+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970718+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-01.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970718+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970718+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970719+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970719+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970719+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970720+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970720+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970720+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970720+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 1394743305,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970721+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970721+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection  to 34.237.153.51:27017 closed
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970721+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970722+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket. (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970722+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970722+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:709:12
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970723+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7) {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970723+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970723+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970724+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970724+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-02.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970724+00:00 app[web.1]: _hostAddress: HostAddress {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970725+00:00 app[web.1]: isIPv6: false,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970725+00:00 app[web.1]: host: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-02.o9elntq.mongodb.net',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970725+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 27017
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970726+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970726+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'ac-ifjm9pr-shard-00-02.o9elntq.mongodb.net:27017',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970726+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970727+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970727+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970727+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970727+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970728+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970728+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970728+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970729+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 1394743101,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970729+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970729+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connection  to 35.169.236.181:27017 closed
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970730+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.onClose (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970738+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket. (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:46)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970738+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970738+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:net:709:12
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970739+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:582:7) {
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970739+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970739+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970740+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970740+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970740+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970740+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970741+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970741+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970742+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: 'atlas-aag0nr-shard-0',
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970742+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970742+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970743+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-08-26T12:28:36.970743+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-26T12:28:37.099460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-26T12:28:37.245818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-08-26T12:28:40.095463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-cove-06913.herokuapp.com request_id=e3475af5-d640-481e-8b58-95f1ed3da665 fwd="154.160.16.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-26T12:28:41.188966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-cove-06913.herokuapp.com request_id=aaec9e5d-c126-4970-a5ac-ca7cd57e2198 fwd="154.160.16.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-26T12:29:14.600906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-cove-06913.herokuapp.com request_id=dc216dd2-c368-4d73-b47a-b51e360c682b fwd="154.160.16.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

```
2022-08-26T12:29:15.093455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-cove-06913.herokuapp.com request_id=3d2648a6-04df-40cb-b15f-8fb9df5f84a1 fwd="154.160.16.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Not much information here, but and that "Connection closed without response" is just for your [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). Not really a problem. Do you have more relevant log output?

Comment: Yes. Let have them sent to you.

Comment: What does that mean? Are you going to edit your question with more information?

Comment: Sorry Chris. I've edit my question with more information.
Kindly help me out.
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like a successful deployment to me: "Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/60d07396-ba9f-4dd8-81ec-ecdfd2f92acd/activity/builds/51734f14-a647-4468-a0e7-22de44979fa0". Have you done that? I also see a number of [H81 Blank App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h81-blank-app) errors: "No code has been pushed to this application. To get rid of this message you need to do one deploy". Are you sure you've pushed your code to Heroku? You committed it locally first? Did you target the `main` or `master` branch, or another one?

Comment: Hello Chris, with regards to the "No code has been pushed to this application", I have succeeded in pushing the app and yes I did target the "master" branch.
There's error when trying to open the app

Comment: Then you're showing us the wrong logs. Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant log output.

Comment: Hello Chris, I've posted the new log output